# WebMoney Check капча

Tags: webmoney, php

Собираюсь упростить для пользователей моего сервиса использование WebMoney check, уменьшив количество ходов.
Использую для этого на своем сайте поля для отправки:
lmi_wmcheck_numberinside (номер чека)
lmi_wmcheck_codeinside (пароль чека)
Требует также проверку капчи (которую недавно ввели), каким полем ее передавать и откуда грузить саму капчу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По скольку WebMoney это платежная система, и требования к безопастности у них повышена, данный вопрос уместнее задать у них на форуме в разделе для разработчиков.

Answer (score -2):

А распознать капчу можно антикапча-сервисом pixodrom (.com)
там меньше чем на антигейте просят - 1$ за 1000 капч. и бесплатный тест есть